# Organize Usings in Visual Studio 2013 doesn't match StyleCop Rules

Tags: visual-studio-2013, stylecop

The organize usings option in Visual Studio 2013 doesn't match the style cop rule SA1208. For example:

The Organize usings would put them in:

```
Namespace.Entities;
Namespace.Interfaces;
System;
System.Linq;
```

But SA108 requires the system ones first.

```
System;
System.Linq;
Namespace.Entities;
Namespace.Interfaces;
```

Is there a way to make visual studio behavior match the StyleCop rule?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, my Visual Studio installation already sorts System usings first.

But you can change it. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514114.aspx) (check the note).

Go to Tools -> Options -> C# (I assume you are working on a C# project) -> Advanced. Then check the box saying "Place 'System' directives first when sorting usings"

**EDIT:**
For recent versions, MS moved the documentation to a different page: see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43f44291.aspx#Automatic%20Code%20Generation) (check the Organize usings section).

Comment: Seems the option is off by default -.- Caught me by surprise too!

Comment: Tools > Options > **Text Editor** > C# > Advanced > Place 'System directive first when sorting usings